# Выдернуть JSON из строки

Tags: linux, json, bash

Строка:

```
"aaa bb {"":{}} nnn nnn"
```

выдернуть надо:

```
{"":{}}
```

Comment: Жалко, не сказали на каком языке.

Comment: [Parsing JSON with Unix tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools)

Answer (score 1):

```
sub=$(echo "${result}"|awk '/{/,/}/');echo $sub
```

Comment: ответ не имеет никакого отношения к меткам вопроса. если нужно на языке, понятном интерпретатору bash, то примерно так: `$ s="aaa bb {\"\":{}} nnn nnn"; s1=${s#*bb}; sub=${s1%%nnn*}`